# How list all Ratpack endpoints?

Tags: ratpack

What's the easiest way to list all endpoints in Ratpack?
My app includes quite a few modules, so simply scanning Ratpack.groovy is not a good solution.  Are there any existing tools to show all the exposed endpoints for the running app?

Answer (score 1):

All routes are lazily generated; from everything that I've seen there isn't a way to do this.  There was discussion back on March 10th on the ratpack slack channel about trying to do this for swagger document generation and that was the consensus.  There's also [an issue](https://github.com/ratpack/ratpack/issues/603) on github that hasn't gotten any attention for doing swagger generation.